# proc report: add indentation on sub-group in lst output

Tags: sas, proc-report

In proc report, I am having difficulty getting the indentation before second level (High Level Term 1) or third level and so on. LEFTMARGIN= doesn't work in this case since it is an lst output.
Is there a way to get indentation aligned for different level?

`    proc printto file="&outpath./&pgm..lst" new;
run;

```
%lastfoot1;
%minjection(reportOID=&title);

%let h1 = Group;
%let h2 = n (%);
%let h3 = Subject years at risk;
%let h4 = AEs per 100 subject years;
%let h5 = Comparison with BFF MDI @320/9.6 ug@Risk diff    95% CI;
%let h6 = Comparison with Symbicort @320 ug@Risk diff    95% CI;


%let undl=%sysfunc(repeat(_,&stndrdls));

proc report data=&data nowd missing headline headskip split='@' formchar(2) ='_' ls=&stndrdls spacing=0         out=qc;

  columns ("&undl" grp coln colc trt c d e f g);

  define grp    / order order=internal noprint;
  define coln    / order order=internal noprint;

  define colc     / group " " left flow width=30 style(column)=[rightmargin=0.25in];
  define trt     / "&h1" left flow width=12 style(column)=[rightmargin=0.25in];
  define c     / "&h2" center flow width=12 style(column)=[rightmargin=0.25in];
  define d     / "&h3" center flow width=12 style(column)=[rightmargin=0.25in];
  define e     / "&h4" center flow width=12 style(column)=[rightmargin=0.25in];
  define f     / "&h5" center flow width=28 style(column)=[rightmargin=0.25in];
  define g     / "&h6" center flow width=28 style(column)=[rightmargin=0.25in];

break after coln   / skip;

&mfooter
run;


proc printto;
run;
```

`

What I got now is:
[image: What I got now is:]

What I want is:
[image: What I want is:]